# How to perform VLOOKUP with wildcards in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So here is my **reference dataframe**, this is the dataframe to sort out the target dataframe:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   3   *   y
2   x   *   *
3   x   4   7
4   1   7   9
5   *   1   z
6   y   1   0
7   3   1   6
```

This is the **target dataframe**:

```
    A   B   C 
0   3   2   y
1   x   5   6
2   2   7   8
4   y   1   0
```

This is my **expected result**:

```
    A   B   C    Result
0   3   2   y     match
1   x   5   6     match
2   2   7   8   no match
4   y   1   0     match
```

I have tried a method which is concatenationg the strings, but it needs a lot of combination columns to filter out the wild card as shown below:

```
    A   B   C   Concat1  Concat2   Concat3
0   1   1   1     1_1      1_1      1_1_1
1   3   *   y     3_        _y      3__y
2   x   *   *          ...
3   x   4   7          ...
4   1   7   9          ...
5   *   1   z          ...
6   y   1   0          ...
7   3   1   6          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just use a loop to check for a match:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def wildcard_vlookup(df_ref, df_target):
    def is_match(row):
        for _, ref_row in df_ref.iterrows():
            if all([(r=='*' or r==v) for r, v in zip(ref_row, row)]):
                return True
        return False
    df_target['Result'] = df_target.apply(is_match, axis=1)
    df_target['Result'] = np.where(df_target['Result'], 'match', 'no match')
    return df_target

data_ref = {
    'A': [1, 3, 'x', 'x', 1, '*', 'y', 3],
    'B': [1, '*', '*', 4, 7, 1, 1, 1],
    'C': [1, 'y', '*', 7, 9, 'z', 0, 6]
}
df_ref = pd.DataFrame(data_ref)
data_target = {
    'A': [3, 'x', 2, 'y'],
    'B': [2, 5, 7, 1],
    'C': ['y', 6, 8, 0]
}
df_target = pd.DataFrame(data_target)
df_result = wildcard_vlookup(df_ref, df_target)
print(df_result)
```

**Output:**

```
   A  B  C    Result
0  3  2  y     match
1  x  5  6     match
2  2  7  8  no match
3  y  1  0     match
```

Comment: currently i have more than 119513 rows for my reference dataframe which sort out a 6526 row target dataframe. This method seems to take too long

Answer (score 0):

Here, your problem is to compare `O(len(df_ref) * len(df_target))` combinations. The problem has a high time complexity naturally.

It is also not trivial, especially because vectorization is hard given your `dtypes` are `object`s (i.e. you are mixing numbers and strings in the same column/row).

You have two options: you either exhaust your time resource (i.e make your code run for a long time) or you space resource (i.e. try to parallelize your operations but at a cost of allocating a lot of memory)

If you have unlimited memory, we can do a `np.equal.outer`

```
c = np.equal.outer(df_target.values, df_ref.values)[:, np.arange(len(df_target.columns)),
                                                    :, np.arange(len(df_ref.columns))].T
```

Now, we compare the desired dimensions and take advantage of broadcasting

```
(c | (df_ref.values == '*')[:, None, :]).all(2).any(0)
```

which yields

```
array([ True,  True, False,  True])
```

A possible speedup is to replace `*` with `np.nan`, and try to get rid of `x` and `y` as to have all `dtypes` be numbers (e.g. make `x` be `9999` or some other factor). Then, we can do `np.isnan(df_ref.values)` above, instead of `df_ref.values == '*'`. It will make it faster, but memory allocation will still be the resource to be exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which is based on the idea of previously converting the rows of the first dataframe and then using regex to get the matches:

```
from itertools import product
import re

aux2 = df2.astype(str).sum(axis=1)
df2['match'] = aux2
aux1 = df1.sum(axis=1).str.replace(r'\*', r'.?', regex=True)

matches = [[x, 'match'] for x, y in product(aux2, aux1) if (re.search(y, x))]

(df2.merge(pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    matches, columns=['match', 'Result']), 
           on='match', how='left')
 .drop('match', axis=1).fillna('no match'))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C    Result
0  3  2  y     match
1  x  5  6     match
2  2  7  8  no match
3  y  1  0     match
```